# Django: Recognizing a recently registered user from the template engine

Tags: django

Is there any way to recognize if the registered user is a recent user, such as registed a day ago from template?

I want to display "how my site works" banner for not logged in or a day of users.

Thanks

Comment: There is a date_joined field on the User model. Maybe consider adding a method or variable to do the true "recently registered logic".

Answer (score 1):

Add a context processor. My example code for users registered in the last hour.

## ExtraContext.py

```
def extra_user_context(request):
    return {'is_recently_register': (datetime.today()-request.user.date_joined).seconds<3600 } if request.user.is_authenticated() else {}
```

## Index.html

```
{% if is_recently_register %}BangGangOfFour{% endif %}
```